# Is It Possible To Launch A List View From A Dynamic Related List Button?

Tags: lightning, related-list

Seeing as the new dynamic related lists have lost the 'View All" link is there a way to create a button that could launch a list view for the appropriate records? I've also toyed with the idea of launching a screen flow that could display all the necessary records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to dynamically filter List Views like this. There are some options:

- You could link to a Report that matches the Dynamic Related List's filters and passes the record ID to a URL parameter to filter it to that record
- If you're considering building a Flow and linking to that, you could just replace it with an embedded Screen Flow that uses the new Data Table to display the related records